# How to create grouped/nested properties?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

I am trying to do nested properties like 'font.family' or 'anchors.fill', but I cannot initialize them in normal way because it prints 'Cannot assign to non-existent property'. Instead I am forced to use Component.onCompleted method. What's wrong?

MyButtonStyling.qml:

```
import QtQml 2.1

QtObject
{
    property QtObject background: QtObject
    {
        property color pressed: "#CCCCCC"
        property color enabled: "#666666"
        property color disabled: "#555555"
    }
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item
{
    width: 400
    height: 300
    MyButton
    {
        text: "TEST"
        styling: MyButtonStyling
        {
            //background.enabled: "#1B2E0A" //Cannot assign to non-existent property "enabled"
            Component.onCompleted:
            {
                background.enabled = "#1B2E0A" //Works
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyButton.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0

Button
{
    property QtObject styling: MyButtonStyling {}

    implicitWidth: 80
    implicitHeight: 80

    style: ButtonStyle
    {
        background: Item
        {
            Rectangle
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: control.pressed ? styling.background.pressed : control.enabled ? styling.background.enabled : styling.background.disabled
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're intending to accomplish with the above code?  There may be a better way to achieve this, but I'm not  entirely clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: With the addition of guini's answer, I would recommend reevaluating the selected answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try replacing your nested `QtObject` with a QML file. For example, I replaced it with `BackgroundTheme.qml`. This way, the property (which can correcly be called "grouped property") works correctly, in a binding and without any error.

BackgroundTheme.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
  property color pressed: "#CCCCCC"
  property color enabled: "#666666"
  property color disabled: "#555555"
}
```

MyButtonStyling.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {       
    property BackgroundTheme background: BackgroundTheme {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the *What's wrong* part of your question.

Your approach does not work, because *left-hand-side expressions are statically typed* in QML.

I had the same problem and found [this comment by Matthew Vogt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26290?focusedCommentId=180206&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-180206) to a QT bug report:

> This behavior is currently correct.
>
> QML is statically typed for left-hand-side expressions, so dynamic properties not present in the static type of a property cannot be resolved in initialization.
>
> The workaround for this issue is to move the declaration of the type to be initialized to its own file, so that it can be declared as a property with a correct static type.

The [previous comment](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26290?focusedCommentId=180139&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-180139) gives a good example:

> This bug is not specifically related to the use of the alias - it results from property lookup during compilation in different units.
>   A simple example:

**Base.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    property QtObject foo: Image {
        property color fg: "red"
    }

    property color bar: foo.fg
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Base {
    foo.fg: "green"
}
```

> Here, 'foo' has the static type 'QtObject' and the dynamic type 'QQuickImage_QML_1'. The lookup of 'fg' is successful in the initialization of 'bar' inside Base.qml, but fails in main.qml.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the right way. But this works

**MyButtonStyling.qml**

```
import QtQml 2.1

QtObject
{
    property alias background: _obj_background

    QtObject 
    {
        id: _obj_background
        property color pressed: "#CCCCCC"
        property color enabled: "#666666"
        property color disabled: "#555555"
    }
}
```

Now using `background.enabled: "#1B2E0A"` in main.qml works.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't seem to work with Qt6. I get the error `Cannot assign to non-existent default property` when trying to do as you suggest.